# <response xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing, bigbluebutton

I'm integrating with BigBlueButton API with Asp Net MVC. But I can't read the response xml file back from api .
It's a force module project.

My code:

```
public ActionResult GetMeetings()
    {
        List<AllMeetings> allMeetings = new List<AllMeetings>();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AllMeetings>), "response");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://bbb.hsu.ac.ir/bigbluebutton/api/getMeetings?checksum=aca692f682f06312cb43f14564ddf96cb76925ed");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        List<AllMeetings> allMeeting =(List<AllMeetings>)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        return View(allMeeting);
    }
```

I coded a class so that I could define attributes as xml element and I use them as an enumerable model

```
namespace BBBJavaScriptTest
   {
[Serializable]
[XmlType("response")]
public class AllMeetings
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "meetingName")]
    public string meetingName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "meetingID")]
    public string meetingID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "createDate")]
    public string createDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "voiceBridge")]
    public string voiceBridge { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "moderatorPW")]
    public string moderatorPW { get; set; }
    public AllMeetings()
    {
            
    }
}
```

and the view part is Razor View:

```
 @model IEnumerable<AllMeetings>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "GetMeetings";
     Layout = null;
  }
 <h2>GetMeetings</h2>

 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
      <td>meetingID</td>
      <td>meetingName</td>
      <td>createDate</td>
      <td>voiceBridge</td>
      <td>moderatorPW</td>
  </tr>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.meetingID</td>
        <td>@item.meetingName</td>
        <td>@item.createDate</td>
        <td>@item.voiceBridge</td>
        <td>@item.moderatorPW</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Response sample:

```
<response>
<returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
<meetings>
    <meeting>
        <meetingName>****</meetingName>
        <meetingID>****</meetingID>
        <internalMeetingID>
            ****
        </internalMeetingID>
        <createTime>1603543982183</createTime>
        <createDate>Sat Oct 24 16:23:02 IRST 2020</createDate>
        <voiceBridge>78409</voiceBridge>
        <dialNumber>****</dialNumber>
        <attendeePW>ap</attendeePW>
        <moderatorPW>mp</moderatorPW>
        <running>true</running>
        <duration>400</duration>
        <hasUserJoined>true</hasUserJoined>
        <recording>false</recording>
        <hasBeenForciblyEnded>false</hasBeenForciblyEnded>
        <startTime>1603543982435</startTime>
        <endTime>0</endTime>
        <participantCount>1</participantCount>
        <listenerCount>1</listenerCount>
        <voiceParticipantCount>0</voiceParticipantCount>
        <videoCount>0</videoCount>
        <maxUsers>0</maxUsers>
        <moderatorCount>1</moderatorCount>
        <attendees>
            <attendee>
                <userID>****</userID>
                <fullName>****</fullName>
                <role>MODERATOR</role>
                <isPresenter>true</isPresenter>
                <isListeningOnly>true</isListeningOnly>
                <hasJoinedVoice>false</hasJoinedVoice>
                <hasVideo>false</hasVideo>
                <clientType>HTML5</clientType>
            </attendee>
        </attendees>
        <metadata> </metadata>
        <isBreakout>false</isBreakout>
    </meeting>
</meetings>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem , And here is the solution  :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        List<AllMeetings> meetings = new List<AllMeetings>();
        foreach (XElement element in    doc.Element("response").Elements("meetings").Elements("meeting"))
        {
            AllMeetings newMeeting = new AllMeetings();
            newMeeting.meetingName = (string)element.Element("meetingName");
            meetings.Add(newMeeting);
        }
        return View(meetings);
```